# Probability that a molecule has 2 binding sites bound

Tags: probability

I am trying to calculate the probability that a large molecule having 2 binding sites (S1 and S2) has both sites bound with 2 different small molecules (say M1 and M2). M1 can only bind to site S1 of the large molecule and M2 can only bind to site S2 of the large molecule. Both sites are independent such that binding of M1 (M2) does not affect binding of M2 (M1).

Without M2, I have the probability to have S1 bound with M1 (say 0.3).

Without M1, I have the probability to have S2 bound with M2 (say 0.6).

Can I say (I guess not !!):

- The probability NOT to have site S1 bound is 1-0.3=0.7.
- The probability NOT to have site S2 bound is 1-0.6=0.4.
- The probability NOT to have both sites bound is 0.7 x 0.4 = 0.28

So the probability to have both sites bound is :

$$1 - 0.7 - 0.4 - 0.28 < 0!!!!$$

Comment: Regarding the last statement, it should be $$1-0.7-0.4\fbox{$ \color{red}+$}0.28$$ This is because while counting the probability not to have the site S1 bound, You are also including the probability that neither of the sites is bound. Again, while calculating the probability that S2 is not bound, you are again including the probability that neither of the sites is bound. So to correct this double calculation, we must add back (The probability that neither is bound), once.

Comment: Yes. Many Thanks !

Comment: You’re welcome. Alternatively, you could also just have done $0.6\times 0.3$.